# How to add html tag inside jade's json

Tags: json, pug

I would like to add an icon tag inside a json that I pass to jade:

```
    - var footerCol3 = {
       'linkList' : [{
           'title': 'link with icon<i class="iconA"></i>', 
           'link': '#'
        }]
      }
```

Or pass a mixing to it

```
    - var footerCol3 = {
       'linkList' : [{
           'title': 'link with icon +someIcon()', 
           'link': '#'
        }]
      }
```

This gets passed to a mixin:

```
   mixin footerColLinks(item)
      - var linkatts = { 'href': item.link }
      a()&attributes(linkatts)= item.title
```

So in the template I will do:

```
+footerColLinks(footerCol3)
```

Maybe is all the mixin processing that is not working? Any ideas?